# Is it possible to connect an LED directly to the GPIO of the Pi?

Tags: gpio, led

I was wondering if it is possible to connect an LED directly to one of the GPIO pins of the Pi? The reason I ask is that, I have read from many sources that if I am not using some sort of break out board, then I run the risk of breaking or frying the pi entirely. And do the GPIO pins provide enough current to power a single LED assuming that it is okay and safe to connect an LED directly to one of the GPIO pins directly?

Thank you.

Comment: The TL;DR answer is yes, but do use a series pull-up or pull-down current limiting resistor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can connect an LED directly to the GPIO pins (it will provide enough current).

However, you probably shouldn't do this for a couple of reasons, You can fry the Pi as you state, and without a current limiting resistor you will signifcantly reduce the life of the LED. This does not mean you need to buy a breakout board to run a single LED. You can use a [simple protection circuit](http://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/Raspberry_Pi_GPIO_Header/Raspberry_Pi_GPIO_Header_Pin_Protection.html) to protect your PI. This [article](http://elinux.org/RPi_Tutorial_EGHS%3aGPIO_Protection_Circuits) has a good discussion on protecting your Pi's GPIO from damage.

If you plan to experiment beyond a simple LED a breakout board that includes GPIO Protection can be a good investment and time saver.

Answer (score 16):

You can connect directly to the IO pins. The GPIO pins on the RasPi processor (BCM2835) supply 3.3v @8ma of drive by default but are programmable as far as pull-up, current, slew rate, etc. see http://www.scribd.com/doc/101830961/GPIO-Pads-Control2 for a summary.

Having said that, unless you're adept at programming those pin parameters, you probably want to limit current with a resistor. Assuming your LED needs 1.5 volts @ 5ma, 3.3v - 1.5v = 1.8v drop. R = E/I so R = 1.8/.005 = 360 ohms should be safe.

Solder this resistor to one leg of the LED. One side of the LED/resistor goes to the GPIO pin, the other side goes to ground.

Comment: Just in case: for 2.25V and 20mA LED, that works out at about 50 ohms, is that right?

Comment: The pin can only source or sink 16ma max, 8ma by default.. You will need a buffer if you truly want to drive the LED with 20ma. If it *could* supply the current then yes... You only need to drop 1.05 volt, so the dropping resistor should be 52 ohms or so.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. So I need to be looking for some more reasonable LEDs. (What's a buffer?)

Comment: 8ma will give you a pretty bright light from a small LED. As far as buffers go, in this case a buffer is a circuit that (for instance) takes a small current drive as an input and sources (or sinks) a much larger current on its output. They are used for driving relatively high current peripherals from low current outputs. An LED is one example, a relay might be another. See http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2012/basics-open-collector-outputs/ for an example of IC buffers. For a discussion of driving LED's with a RasPi see http://elinux.org/RPi_Tutorial_EGHS:LED_output

Comment: From the linked document: "The current value specifies the maximum current under which the pad will still meet the specification. IT IS NOT: The current the pad will deliver. IT IS NOT: a current limit so the pad will not blow up. The pad output is a voltage source." This means that you can't limit the current with programming, and you DO NEED a resistor to limit the current to your LED.

Answer (score 0):

There are LEDs with an integrated resistor which can directly be used with 5V, or possibly 3.3V

http://www.mouser.lu/new/kingbright/kingbright-resistor-LEDs/