# How to attach a IR led to a GPIO port?

Tags: gpio

I would like to use one GPIO port to send IR signals in order to control some hifi components. Most IR codes are based on a 36kHz signal. I found an test of someone how measured the maximum speed of a GPIO port. The text is only in [German](http://hobbyelektronik.org/w/index.php/Raspberry_Pi_IO) but the result is, that the GPIO port has a maximum speed of about 11MHz. So it should be possible to encode the IR codes fully in software. But there is still the question how to drive the IR led.

I found an [short article](http://www.lirc.org/transmitters.html) which describes a circuit for a 5V power supply. I am wondering if the 5V of the Rpi can be used. Does anybody know a circuit that can be used with the Rpi without damaging the device?

I need a range of about 5m. This is quite much. Is the Rpi able to power such an IR led?

Comment: Take a look at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3980 for suggestions about driving an LED from the RasPi GPIO port...

Comment: A simple LED is easy, because it does not need much power. A IR LED needs more power.

Comment: If you look at the referenced links (in the comments) you'll see that there are some driver circuits described. These should be able to drive any reasonable current requirements.

Comment: I've tried to do this and the problem I ran into is that while the Pi can do GPIO at that speed, it can't do it consistently. There's some signal wobble as the Pi won't operate in real-time. So you get really close to the signal you want to send, but not exactly it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the comments on you post suggest (in the links). The best way to do that is to switch a transistor which in it's turn drives the LED. That way the GPIO pins do not have to deal with the currents that might flow through the LED.

I found a [nice document](http://picprojects.org.uk/projects/inf/drivingLEDs.pdf) that explains this into great detail (but in the end it doesn't differ very much from the info already given to you). This document is written with a PIC in mind that controls the transistor, so you might need to change the value of the resistor connected to the base of the transistor.